# jQuery .stop() breaks subsequent animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to make an accordion-like menu with jQuery, but it refuses to cooperate: http://jsfiddle.net/vrcpK/1/

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$('#submenu div.submenu').hover(function() {
    $('.submenu-head', this).addClass('visible');

    $(this).siblings().each(function() {
        $('div.submenu-body', this).stop(true).slideUp('slow');
        $('p.submenu-head', this).removeClass('visible');
    });

    $('div.submenu-body', this).stop(true).slideDown(500);
}, function() {
    $('.submenu-head', this).removeClass('visible');

    $('div.submenu-body', this).stop(true).slideUp('slow');
});​
```

When you hover over an item twice, the menu dies and slowly shrivels up. After that, it lethargically reveals a third of the content.

I suspect it is a problem with my `.stop(true)` calls, but I can't figure out any other way to keep the menu from becoming gelatin after moving the mouse over it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the height is set to whatever it is when hover out... try reseting the height to auto when the slide up is complete...

```
$('div.submenu-body', this).stop().slideUp('slow', function() {
  $(this).height('auto');
});
```

Comment: That's definitely it! Thank you so much.